# Server running out of memory with Docker and Windows Nano

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

I've got a VM running Windows Nano and Docker containers. The Docker containers are all running ASP.NET Core 5 apps. I'm coming across this really weird bug where the VM is running out of memory, and the Task Manager, Process Explorer do not show what is taking up all this memory:
[image]
[image]

What I'm observing is that when I kill one of the containers, a lot of memory gets returned so it's definitely caused by a Docker container. The question is, how do I go about diagnosing this problem?

I've tried to take a memory dump of the app in the container I killed, but the dump is no larger than 1GB.

Comment: `docker stats` should at least be able to show you how much memory each container is using. I have no experience with windows containers, so how to go about diognosing each individual container I have no idea.

Comment: If you look at the second screenshot, that is the `docker stats` view from powershell. I'm seeing a total of no more than 5GB of memory usage from the containers. The memory usage reported by `docker stats` match what I am seeing on Task Manager.